# Apply Rotate+Crop to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I've looking for a quick and method apply both transformations to a BitmapImage.

I want to apply to create a new modified bitmap, so not using RotateTransform in the GUI.

- The input should be the original BitmapSource.

  - The return should be **a copy of the input, but rotated and cropped.**

NOTE: The rotation will be angles from 0 to 270, in steps of 90 degress.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7309086/1870760

Comment: @JameyD Did you even read the question? No RotateTransform. I want to get a MODIFIED version of the original (input) BitmapImage.

Comment: You just clone that BitmapImage then and then modify that version.

Comment: Modify by doing what?

Comment: You clone the BitMapImage, now you have a copied version of this image, you modify that version using the method in the linked question.

Comment: Do you mean, a RotateTransform? What about the Crop? Also, could I save the modified version to a file? If not, then it's not what I want.

Comment: As pointed out by Jamey, you would use a `TransformedBitmap` for the rotation. In addition, you would use a `CroppedBitmap` for the crop. Then save the resulting bitmap by one of WPF's `BitmapEncoder`s.

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22014499/1136211, with a RotateTransform instead of a ScaleTransform.